# What control to use to display larger image on Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I would like to display a larger image on a windows phone 7 device. I need to be able to zoom in and out using multi-touch gesture. I was wondering if there is any control that can do this out of the box in the Windows Phone 7 SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use DeepZoom, you could also use a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=VS.95).aspx) to contain the Image, and listen for the pinch touch gestures/events and zoom in and out of the ViewBox using a RenderTransform.

Below is some code that I used for a Silverlight app, which with some work could be changed to react to Pinch and touch gestures instead of mousewheel + click/drag events. It might be possible to also change the amount of zoom depending on the "strength" of the pinch gesture.

For a viewbox defined in XAML:

```
    <Border Name="viewboxBackground" Background="Black">
            <Viewbox Name="viewboxMain">
                <!--your content here -->
            </Viewbox>
    </Border>
```

Codebehind:

```
    #region Pan and Zoom Events and Handlers

    void MouseClickHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseClickPos = e.GetPosition(viewboxBackground);
        bMoving = true;
    }

    void MouseMoveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (bMoving)
        {
            //get current transform
            CompositeTransform transform = viewboxMain.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

            Point currentPos = e.GetPosition(viewboxBackground);
            transform.TranslateX += (currentPos.X - _mouseClickPos.X);
            transform.TranslateY += (currentPos.Y - _mouseClickPos.Y);

            viewboxMain.RenderTransform = transform;

            _mouseClickPos = currentPos;
        }
    }

    void MouseReleaseHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        bMoving = false;
    }

    void MouseWheelZoom(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            _zoomMultiplier += _zoomRate;
            ApplyZoomTransform(viewboxMain, _zoomMultiplier, new Point(viewboxMain.ActualWidth / 2, viewboxMain.ActualHeight / 2));
        }
        else if (e.Delta < 0 && _zoomMultiplier > 1)
        {
            _zoomMultiplier -= _zoomRate;
            ApplyZoomTransform(viewboxMain, _zoomMultiplier, new Point(viewboxMain.ActualWidth / 2, viewboxMain.ActualHeight / 2));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element"></param>
    /// <param name="iZoomFactor"></param>
    /// <param name="zoomCenter">If provided, the zoom will be centered around the given position.</param>
    void ApplyZoomTransform(UIElement element, double iZoomFactor, Point? zoomCenter)
    {
        //get current transform
        CompositeTransform transform = viewboxMain.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

        if (zoomCenter != null)
        {
            transform.CenterX = zoomCenter.GetValueOrDefault().X;
            transform.CenterY = zoomCenter.GetValueOrDefault().Y;
        }
        transform.ScaleX = iZoomFactor;
        transform.ScaleY = iZoomFactor;

        element.RenderTransform = transform;
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Please note that I haven't actually tested this on Windows Phone 7, but I'm pretty sure ViewBox and RenderTransform (which is what you really need to implement the zoom functionality) is available for use.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample and the suggestion of using the Viewbox control. Maybe the use of ViewBox and adding the multi-touch behaviour is the way I need to use this. I will report back after trying the combination of these techniques.

Comment: Someone pointed out to me that the code above is missing the constructor for the CompositeTransform, so the code above will complain at the line: "CompositeTransform transform = viewboxMain.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;" - to fix this, you can just create a CompositeTransform() at some point (maybe in the page constructor) and assign it to the ViewBox :)

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam, but you might also find this example project useful - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/31/sample-code-from-teched-new-zealand-talks.aspx (look for the Drag and Pinch gestures in part one). This link on using XNA on WP7 for touch gesture recognition might also be useful - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/07/12/touch-gestures-on-windows-phone-7.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [DeepZoom](https://web.archive.org/web/20150908180555/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/priozersk/archive/2010/03/28/deep-zoom-on-wp7.aspx). Not sure how well it supports multi-touch gesture out the box, but you can learn about using [gestures here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150528165142/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/08/31/xna-from-silverlight-on-windows-phone-7-gestures.aspx) and simulating multi-touch [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815211129/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/07/12/multitouch-behavior-update-for-windows-phone-7-tools-beta.aspx), if multi-touch support isn't standard.
Here's an example video of [DeepZoom on WP7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgW-p0PxdtQ).

Comment: +1 Thanks for your comment. The GalaSoft link (http://www.galasoft.ch/Touch/) is very usefull. Now I understand it is possible to add a behaviour to the control and enable the multitouch support on the control this way.

Answer (score 1):

You may also find Laurent Bugnion's multitouch behaviour worth a look for zooming images.

[MultiTouch Behavior for Windows Phone 7](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/07/04/multitouch-behavior-for-windows-phone-7-videos-wp7dev.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+galasoft+%28Laurent+Bugnion+%28GalaSoft%29%29&utm_content=Twitter)